# How do you build up a LIKE condition in a db_select() query?

Tags: database

How do you build up a [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) condition in a [`db_select()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7) query?

I know how to do this with a [`db_query()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7) API call, but is there a special syntax / method for doing this with `db_select()`?

Comment: Just for future reference, _anything_ that you can pass to `db_query` as an argument placeholder, you can also pass as an argument to `...Query::condition`. You won't find documentation for each individual operator for each different type of query, as it wouldn't make sense to do that. It all goes through PDO at the end of the day, if `db_like` prepares a variable correctly for `db_query`, then by definition it will prepare the same variable correctly for `db_select`

Comment: Before anyone suggests it, unless you can find question  about db_select + LIKE, I don't think we have a dup of this.  We have, db_query + LIKE, but even though the answer is the same, the question is different.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After digging through Drupal Documentation found a solution in [db_like](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_like/7) API documentation page and [SelectQuery:condition](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3a%3acondition/7) handler doc page..

For example

```
$result = db_select('field_data_field_name', 'f')->fields('f', array(
    'entity_id',
    'field_name_value'
))
->condition('entity_type', 'user')
->condition('bundle', 'user')
->condition('deleted', 0)
->condition('field_name_value', '%' . db_like($last_item) . '%', 'LIKE')
->distinct()
->range(0, 10)
->execute();
```

Condition to use for like query is

```
->condition('field_name_value', '%' . db_like($last_item) . '%', 'LIKE')
```

Comment: The two things to notice here are that (1) `db_like()` is needed to properly escape the argument, and (2) you need to explicitly add the wildcard characters.  It will also use the default collation on the database, and I don't think there is any way to specify a different one.

Comment: I may take a pass later today at making this a little more comprehensive.  I can never remember the DB API, and was literally looking up the same thing yesterday.

Answer (score 4):

In Drupal 8 and higher versions, you need to use `Drupal\Core\Database\Database`, as in the following code.

```php
$database = Database::getConnection();
$query = $database->select('TABLE NAME', 'u')
    ->fields('u', array('column1','column2'));
$query->condition('column1', '%'.$database->escapeLike($search_phrase) . '%', 'LIKE');
```

Alternatively, you can use this code.

```php
$db_or = $query->orConditionGroup()
 ->condition('column1', '%' . $database->escapeLike($search_phrase) . '%', 'LIKE')
 ->condition('column2', $database->escapeLike($search_phrase) . '%', 'LIKE')
 ->condition('column1', '%' . $database->escapeLike($search_phrase), 'LIKE');
$query->condition($db_or);
$result = $query->execute();
```

Comment: I prefer this solution, since it's using the built in database function (escapeLike) instead of a global "db_like()". Also mentioning all the three possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

For using "like" in `db_select` is as below and worked for me...

```
$search_value = "testvalue@xmail.com";
$query = db_select('TABLE NAME', 'u');
$query->fields('u', ['ROW1', 'ROW2']);
$query->condition('ROW1', '%' . db_like($search_value) . '%', 'LIKE');
$result = $query->execute();
```

Here exact value in ROW1 is "testvalue@xmail.com" and by using `LIKE` condition in `db_select` I got the output as "testvalue@xmail.com".

Answer (score 1):

The following code works in Drupal 8.x, but it won't work in Drupal 9.x, as `db_like()` has been removed.

```php
$connection = \Drupal::database();
$query = $connection ->select('node', 'n');
$query->fields('n');
$query->condition('nid', '%'.db_like($exp), 'LIKE');
$records = $query->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [db_like() is deprecated in Drupal 8.x](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21database.inc/function/db_like/8.2.x) and removed in Drupal 9.x, the documentation suggests to use [Connection::escapeLike()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Connection.php/function/Connection%3A%3AescapeLike/8.2.x) instead.

The following code works in Drupal 8 and 9.

```php
$connection = Database::getConnection();
$query = $connection->select('your_table_name', 'table_alias')
  ->fields('table_alias', ['whatever_field', 'other_field'])
  ->condition('my_field_name', '%' . $connection->escapeLike($yourSearchString) . '%', 'LIKE');

$result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

For code that injected the *database* service in `$this->database`. the following is the code I would use in Drupal 9.x.

```php
$escaped = $this->database->escapeLike($input);
$query = $this->database->select('zipcodes', 'z');
$query->fields('z', ['city', 'zip', 'state']);
$orGroup = $query->orConditionGroup()
  ->condition('city', '%' . $escaped . '%', 'LIKE')
  ->condition('z.zip', '%' . $escaped . '%', 'LIKE');

$query->condition($orGroup);
$query->range(0, 10);
$result = $query->execute();
if (!empty($result)) {
  foreach ($result as $record) {
    $string = $record->city . ' ' .$record->state. ' - ' .$record->zip;
    $value_string = $record->city. '~' .$record->state. '~' .$record->zip;
    $data[] = [
      'label' => $string,
      'value' => $value_string,
    ];
  }
}
```